# Some .post-tag anchors missing titles

Tags: bug, tags

Inside the `#question` div, it seems some tags don't properly set the title attribute of the anchors linking each tag to the question list of that tag. "Show questions tagged with ..." is the text that usually appears.

```
<a rel="tag" title="" class="post-tag js-gps-track" href="/questions/tagged/sizeof">sizeof</a>
```

I think it should be like:

```
<a rel="tag" title="Show questions tagged with signalr-hub" class="post-tag js-gps-track" href="/questions/tagged/signalr-hub">signalr-hub</a>
```

I've looked down a few questions, and the first tag appears to always be missing the above text in the title attribute, but sometimes, so too does the second tag when there are 3 or more tags.